# Концепт VS концепция

Tags: значения, выбор-слова

В чем семантическая разница между словами «концепт» и «концепция»?

Верно ли говорить «концепт добра и зла»? Различие между лево и право — это концепция? Любовь — это концепт?

Comment: В "концепте добра и зла" это, по-моему, варваризм, гладко заменимый  на "понятие" или "представление о"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Концепт](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%82) это больше предметная сторона вопроса, воплощение идеи, или предмет.

[Концепция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) это больше идеологическая сторона вопроса, сама идея или набор система идей.

Соответствующие статьи википедии вполне адекватно отражают различие и способы употребления.

В тоже время у терминов есть свой спектр и определенная гибкость, и в зависимости от того, какой аспект вы хотите подчеркнуть, могут быть использованы нетрадиционно.

Концепция добра и зла - это устоявшееся выражение, обозначающее набор ценностей определяющий само понятие, разделяющее безличное на две новые формы, и при дальнейшем развитии позволяющий классифицировать явления, события, предметы и тд по наличию или отсутствию добра и зла(признаков, воплощений). Это не две разные концепции, это одна концепция *о том то* и *том то*.

В зависимости от контекста, возможно употребление и *концепт добра и зла*, к примеру в качестве сарказма или шутки, применительно к описанию конкретного человека, к примеру в качестве замены *воплощение добра и зла* по причине того, что *воплощение* более сильная коннотация, оставляющая меньше(или совсем не оставляющая) места для наличия других свойств, особенно когда смешано не смешиваемое(обычно все-таки или одно или другое; когда и то и другое, да еще и воплощение - это что то действительно особенно из ряда вон выходящее)

Концепт применительно к предметам, имеет больше окраску неопределенности, временности и возможности изменения в будущем. Концепт, набросок, эскиз.

Лево и право - как стороны света, это не концепция, это направления. Концепция, если можно так сказать, или элементы этой концепции в данном случае, это левая рука и правая рука - само их разделение, и они в свою очередь позволяют классифицировать стороны света, направления и тд. Те концепция левого и правого в общем и ее атрибуты в виде рук - это концепция.

Левоцетрисскоправоультврофиолетовые и все возможные сочетания - определенно образуют систему с некоторыми правилами классификации и базис всего этого, это концепция чего то там.

Любовь это своего рода термин, имеющий значение в контексте, описывающий некоторое состояние. И как термин не является концептом или концепцией сам по себе.

Однако система представлений или убеждений, позволяющая классифицировать наличие или отсутствие любви, является концепцией(представлением), определяющее место явлений.
К примеру такой пассаж, [источник](http://www.lyubi.ru/phil7.5.4.php):

> Дантовская концепция любви раскрывается в символической картине Россетти "Любовь Данте". В центре композиции - крылатый Амур с луком и стрелами на фоне звездного неба. В верхнем левом и нижнем правом углу картины изображены лица Данте и Беатриче как лики солнца и луны. На одном из ранних эскизов к картине была надпись на итальянском языке: "Любовь движет солнцем и другими звездами".

Его представление, и место явления в его мировоззрении выраженное символами.

Концепция это те незримые связи, которые объединяют явления и предметы в систему и определяют их положение в мире. И их можно в какой то степени выразить, определить, через через предметы и явления, и их отношения между собой.

Answer (score 5):

На мой взгляд, во всех Ваших примерах должна быть "концепция". То есть, некая достаточно абстрактная система взаимосвязанных понятий,  взглядов, идей. А "концепт" - это вещь более конкретная, примерно как "задумка", "набросок", "проект" или даже уже готовый опытный образец, прототип. Например, может быть концепт нового мобильного телефона, автомобиля или космического корабля. Но никак не добра и зла, любви, эволюции, строения атома, происхождения Вселенной и прочих подобных вещей.

Comment: концепты, ну в каком то смысле, строения атома как раз таки были ))

Comment: @MolbOrg, я не знала, а можно пример? Наверное, там скорее что-то вроде наглядной модели атома, а не сложной размашистой теории? Кстати, наглядность, пусть даже в ущерб качеству - это важное свойство концептов, которое далеко не всегда присуще концепциям.

Comment: да, это модель атома, в принципе сама концепция возможности существования атома имеет давнюю историю [Атомизм](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Атомизм), полностью воображаемая чисто концептуально определенная. И в начале 20 века там тоже не сразу определились что есть что(модель атома Томсона, модель атома Резерфорда), и до появления возможности посмотреть в электронный микроскоп, это все таки была воображаемая частица определенная через свойства и взаимодействия с объектами, со временем наши представления обрели более конкретную и определенную форму, и стали клиническим фактом.

Answer (score 4):

"Концепт" isn't really a word. It's just a calque of "concept", that actually means "концепция". 
There are some Russian philosophical schools that seem to define that term to depict something different, but it never goes beyond anything that would be easily described by another, "normal" word (like "смысl" - meaning, or "понятие" - notion). In any event, unless you are speaking to a specialized philosophical forum, simply don't use that word. "Концепция" is the proper translation of "concept". "Концепт" is simply a calque. It's not really a Russian word.

And yes, it had first appeared in the language some 400 years ago, but it meant a completely different thing back than, and had completely fallen out of use before reappearing again in our days. It was a completely different word back than for all practical purposes, just happened to be spelled the same way.

Comment: How is it "not really a word"? As long as it's used it *is* a word, it means something. ("calc" isn't a word though ;-))

Comment: Re. "calc", I meant "calque" of course. Not sure what my phone meant when it "corrected" it. Re. "not a word", it may be an exaggeration, I just mean, it's not much more of a word than "манагер" or "крайм". Not everything that's "used" deserves to be called "a word". Both examples above are used sometimes (I heard it). "Calc" is also often used btw (in reference to a claculator), especially in written speech. None of those are really "words". And neither is "концепт".

Comment: Шоб вы знали, «концепт» цэ то шо по английски «conceit».

Answer (score 1):

Вам тут вообще никому не понять, что такое «концепт», ибо это понятие из эпохи настолько вам чуждой, что даже аналогию степени чуждости этого понятия вам мне подобрать навряд ли удастся. «Концепт» – это сердце-окно из сонета Шекспира, в которое девушка смотрит, и бесконечно видит свои отражения, это блоха Джона Донна, которая укусила парня и девушку, и внутри которой произошло то, что иначе не произойдёт, в её желудке смешалась их кровь, это воплощение высшего творчества Лос из пророческих книг Уильяма Блейка.

Comment: вау, какая превосходная форма.